# Modular arithmetic with complex modulus.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory

If $n,a\in\Bbb Z$ and $0<a<n$ then we know that $u\equiv n\bmod a$ iff $n=at+u$ holds for some $t\in\Bbb Z$.

Suppose $a=b+i$ where $i^2=-1$ what is $n\bmod a$ for cases $n\in\Bbb Z$ and when $n\in\Bbb Z[i]$?

Does it have interpretation of smallest remainder?

Comment: Good question, possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213942/modulo-operations-over-gaussian-integers

Comment: Search on [Gaussian Euclidean algorithm](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=gaussian+euclidean+algorithm) to find many prior posts on this topic $\,(\Bbb Z[i]\,$ is know as the Gaussian integers).

Comment: @BillDubuque I wouldn't have used $\Bbb Z[i]$ without knowing Gaussian Integers.

Comment: This may help you: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/Zinotes.pdf